# Search in active directory forest

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I have multiple domains in our Active Directory like below:

pnc.com → root domain
europe.pnc.com → Child domain
asia.pnc.com → Child domain
americas.pnc.com → Child domain

I want a write a VBScript that can search for a user in entire forest and show me the location of the user object.

I have tried in the past searching like this but I had to give the exact domain name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [referral chasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for subordinate domains:

```vbs
Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

base   = "<LDAP://" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person))"
attr   = "distinguishedName"
scope  = "subtree"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.Properties("Chase referrals") = &h20
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & filter & ";" & attr & ";" & scope

Set rs = cmd.Execute
...
```

Back in the day I wrote a [wrapper class for AD queries](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml), which enables this by default:

```vbs
'add/import class here

Set qry = New ADQuery
qry.Filter     = "..."
qry.Attributes = Array("sAMAccountName", ...)

Set rs = qry.Execute
...
```